# reinstalling phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

EDIT:: installed mysql-server but no phpmyadmin (since phpmyadmin was installed before mysql, that resulted an error). How to reinstall phpmyadmin with database (there is no phpmyadmin datbase)? unstalling it and reinstalling it didn't help.

i was trying to install phpmyadmin (and zend framework) through synaptic manager but in the middle i was prompted for password

i thought it was phpmyadmin password and i proceeded but i got error and i aborted. and then again i tried to reinstall, it reinstalled but i am not getting phpmyadmin.

### EDIT::The following is invalid so please don't bother

apache is running but mysql is not

some of it's characteristics are:

```
santosh@explorer:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

santosh@explorer:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily  
unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/),
is another process using it?
```

Should i be asking this question here or stackoverflow?

UPDATES::

after restarting my computer

```
 santosh@explorer:~$ sudo service mysql start
 [sudo] password for santosh: 
 mysql: unrecognized service
```

UPDATES::

```
santosh@explorer:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other process is lock your update manager. restart your computer.

to start mysql server, you can use this command :

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: santosh@explorer:~$ sudo service mysql start
mysql: unrecognized service

Comment: in that case you don't have mysql installed, do: sudo apt-get install mysql

Comment: did not work see update above

Answer (score 1):

This is because another process is running.So please run this command:

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

That will show you the PID and run this command:

```
sudo kill PID
```

If this doesn't works run:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

And then try to reinstall phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

to install mysql server :

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1`

Answer (score 0):

Consider [removing phpMyAdmin completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262941/how-do-i-completely-remove-phpmyadmin) and then re-installing it. It should work fine.

Still if 'apache is running and not mySQL' ,then try re-installing mySQL too

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 --reinstall
```

If this doesn't allow you to reconfigure the package you can use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
```

This shall make your LAMP installation look fresh!!!