# How do I completely remove phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I messed up my `phpmyadmin`, I haven't logged in `phpmyadmin` for a while and as a result I forgot my password.

I decided to purge PHPMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

I did get some error messages asking for my password, but I forgot that, so I just pressed ignore, after that, I installed `phpmyadmin` again:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

But now, when I logging to my `phpmyadmin`, I get a `404 not found` error page!?

> How do i completely remove phpmyadmin?

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might want to try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 28):

You have to remove total.  I mean `sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*`

Comment: Plz note that there is note that there is **no sapce** between the 'phpmyadmin' and *.
P.S. - cost me a lot yesterday.

Comment: @Yes there is no space.

Comment: I was actually telling that to @blade19899, so as to save him from the mistake that i did.